# How to select the complete word within the brackets even if it have that brackets within word

Tags: c++, regex

Give some solution to this following example,

**Scenario-1:**

My String : `Password={my_pswd}}123}`

I want to select the value enclosed within the {} brackets(Example: I want to select the complete password key value `{my_pswd}123}` not `{my_pswd}`)

If I'm using this regex `\{(.*?)\}` , this will select `{my_pswd}` not `{my_pswd}}123}`. So how to get complete word even if the word has } in between? Give me some suggestions by using regex or any other way.

**Scenario-2:**
I am using this regex `^\{|\}$` . If my string have both `{` bracket and `}` bracket like this `{{my_password}}` then only it want to select first and last bracket. If my string like this `{{my_password`, it don't want to select that starting bracket. Its like AND condition in Regex. I referred many posts they did with look up but I can't get clear idea. Give me some suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174101/discussion-on-question-by-piraisudan-m-how-to-select-the-complete-word-within-th).

Comment: See my answer, there is a demo, everything works as expected. If you test the patterns anywhere at online testers, use `^\{([\s\S]*)\}$` or `/^\{(.*)\}$/gs`

Comment: You are using the wrong option at regex101.com, why at all are you using it? See https://regex101.com/r/qCwcfi/2 with the JS option selected, it shows the regex works well **for that right flavor**. And see https://ideone.com/5wgIzu, it **proves** the regex is working with `std::regex`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks for your clear explanation. Now I got it and solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `{...}` substrings you want to match must be followed with `;` or end of string.
This will not work for cases when a `}` inside the values can also be followed with `;`.

You may solve the first issue by adding a `(?![^;])` lookaround:

```
\{(.*?)\}(?![^;])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NYxqGu/1).

**Details**

- `\{` - a `{` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `\}` - a `}` char
- `(?![^;])` - no char other than `;` is allowed right after the current position

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/LytNlV):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    const std::regex reg("\\{(.*?)\\}(?![^;])");
    std::smatch match;
    std::string s = "Username={My_{}user};Password={my_pswd}}123}}}kk};Password={my_pswd}}123}";
    std::vector<std::string> results(
        std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), reg, 1), // See 1, it extracts Group 1 value
        std::sregex_token_iterator());
    for (auto result : results)
    {
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
My_{}user
my_pswd}}123}}}kk
my_pswd}}123
```

As for the second scenario, you may use

```
std::regex reg("^\\{([^]*)\\}$");
std::string s = "{My_{}user}";
std::cout << regex_replace(s, reg, "$1") << std::endl; // => My_{}user
```

See [another C++ demo](https://ideone.com/5wgIzu).

The `\{([^]*)\}$` pattern matches the `{` at the start (`^`) of the string, then matches and captures into Group 1 (later referenced with the help of `$1` in the replacement pattern) any 0+ chars, as many as possible, and then matches a `}` at the end of the string (`$`).